Different statements for Frobenius reciprocity
I know the following statement of Frobenius reciprocity and how to prove it:
Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be its subgroup. Let also $V$ be a representation of $G$ and $W$ a representation of $H$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}_{G}(V;\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}W)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}_{H}(\mathrm{Res}_{H}^{G}V;W)$.
I need to show another version of it. Namely, that if $W$ is an irreducible representation of $H$ and if $W$ is contained inside of restriction $\mathrm{Res}_{H}^{G}V$ of an arbitrary representation $V$ of $G$. Then there is a $G$-equivariant map $\varphi$ from $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}W$ to $V$.
Do I understand correctly, that this can be proven by saying, that if $W$ is embedded into $\mathrm{Res}_{H}^{G} V$, then there is a backwards projection from $\mathrm{Res}_{H}^{G} V$ to $W$? Hence, by the stated above, there is a natural unique map from $V$ to $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}W$. However, I don't understand, why there is a backwards map.

It depends on your definition of induction. Confusingly there are two versions of induction, the left adjoint to restriction (which is a stronger version of your second version of Frobenius reciprocity) and the right adjoint (which is the first version), and they are naturally isomorphic but only if $H$ has finite index in $G$.

And yes, there is a backwards map, and this follows from semisimplicity (so we need to work over a suitable field). Also you really mean a nonzero $G$-equivariant map.
